# How do you find the target of a symlink created with mklink

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Once a symlink is created using mklink, is there any way to find the link target, other than parsing the output of dir command ?

As an example, `junction.exe` will return the substitute name when called with a junction as a first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use junction.exe on links made with mklink or you can use the GUI tool [NTFSLinksView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html)

Comment: Junction works fine as of version 1.06. Thanks

Comment: I’d mention that `junction.exe` is a part of SysInternals and can be downloaded from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx. Unfortunately, it still makes an extensive output you need to parse…

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser Julian Knight's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/444040/659759) worked for me.

> With Windows Link Shell Extension installed, you can right-click on the link in Windows Explorer and check the properties. There is a tab that allows you to change the link directly.

With [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) installed:

- When you right-click a file to open up "Properties" window, it includes an additional  tab: "Link Properties", showing the Target of symlinks.
- You can also edit this Target field to change the symlink's target.
- And since the field is editable, copy-paste of the target link is easy.
- As is scrolling to see the entire path of the target file!
  (In contrast, the "Location" field elsewhere in the Properties window does NOT allow scrolling to see the full path of the file you're examining.)

His SuperUser answer also lists resources to Windows equivalents for Linux commands (including `ln.exe`).